# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, terminal

I'm trying to embed the android terminal emulator project in my project, but I always got an error of NoClassDefFoundError. I already add the jackpal_androidterm_emulator.jar but the error stays the same.

BTW, I don't know what code will I add in the Manifest, I just add

```
<activity name=".Term"></activity>
```

What else will I do? Please help me. Thanks!

```
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jackpal.androidterm.Term
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at com.example.ttg.fragment.LinuxCommands.onListItemClick(LinuxCommands.java:91)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
12-18 04:14:52.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does your manifest look like? Do you have `package` specified on the `<manifest>` element?

Comment: this meant your `class` is not found at runtime...

Comment: Yes i have. <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ttg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Answer (score 0):

First try to clean your project. IF this doesn't solve the issue then:

Go from: *Project-> Properties-> Java Build Path-> Order & Export*. Check all the Android Private Libraries for your project and clean project again.

**N.B.** A good intro about the error [On JavaCodeGeeks](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-how-to-solve-no-class-def-found-error/)

Comment: restarted the eclipse after doing this?

Comment: Also try adding full name of the activity in the manifest. `com.xxx.your_activity`

Comment: I've restarted and change the activity name into its complete full name but the error still the same.